# Unable to figure out the async nature of the $http call

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

My  controller/service retrieve the data from the url, and it returns with no errors. However, the repeat for the <tbody> doesn't show the data. The inspector shows no errors, and fiddler shows the url is called for the rest api.

Model

```
    export interface IAuthor {
    AuthorId: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    GoogleAuthorId: string;
    CreatedByEmployeeId: any;
    CreatedOn: Date;
    ModifiedByEmployeeId: any;
    ModifiedOn: Date;
    PhotoURI: string;
}
```

Service

```
    export class AuthorService implements IAuthorService {
    private url: string;
    static $inject = ["$http"];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        this.url = "/odata/Author";
    }

    getAuthors(): ng.IPromise<IAuthor[]> {
        return this.$http
            .get(this.url)
            .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IAuthor[]>): IAuthor[] => {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    export class AuthorController implements IAuthorController {
    authorItems: IAuthor[];
    static $inject: string[] = ["AuthorService"];

    constructor(private authorService: Services.IAuthorService) {
        var results = this.getAuthors();

    }

    getAuthors(): IAuthor[] {
        this.authorItems = [];
        var results = this.authorService.getAuthors()
            .then((authorItemsLocal: IAuthor[]): void => {
                this.authorItems = authorItemsLocal;

            });

        return this.authorItems;
    }
}
```

Html

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AuthorController as vm">

    <h2>Authors</h2>

    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Author ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="c in vm.authorItems">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ c.FirstName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.LastName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ c.AuthorId }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a debugging step, does anything show up if you put some placeholder items in the `authorItems` property in the class constructor?

Comment: I've initialized it with items, and it still wipes the items out and there is two empty rows after.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong, can you show us how you register your controller? You sould log in the console the result of the call `this.authorService.getAuthors()` and show the result.

Answer (score 0):

I had typed the results to the proper type in typescript. When I typed them to "any", it worked.